# Why are my arguments undefined in python when I call my function?

Tags: python, function

I am trying to make a program which gives me the amount of minutes before the two boats collide. the boats are going 60 knot and 70 knot, and the distance between them is 455km. I get an error saying that route, boat_speed and crash is not defined.

```
def knot_to_km(knot):
    return (knot * 1.852)     

def time_of_impact(route, boat_speed, crash):
    route = 455
    boat_speed = (knot_to_km(60) + knot_to_km(70))
    crash = ((route / boat_speed) / 60)
    return(crash)

print(time_of_impact(route, boat_speed, crash))
```

Comment: what is your actual values of `route, boat_speed, crash` variables? define them before you pass them in as an argument to your function.

Comment: @mightyandweakcoder route is meant to be 455km, boat speed is 60 times 1.852 + 70 times 1.852, crash is just being used for putting the formula together but I guess that isn't necessary?

Comment: In Python, write this: `return(xyz)` like this: `return xyz` without parentheses.

Comment: It's also worth getting in the habit of using good function names. For example: `knot_to_km` is not the best choice. `knots_to_kph` (or kmh) would be more accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A parameter is a value for input to a function, not for declaring a variable in a function.

```
def knot_to_km(knot):
    return (knot * 1.852)     

def time_of_impact():
    route = 455
    boat_speed = (knot_to_km(60) + knot_to_km(70))
    crash = ((route / boat_speed) / 60)
    return(crash)

print(time_of_impact())
```

or

```
def knot_to_km(knot):
    return (knot * 1.852)     

def time_of_impact(route, boat_speed):
    crash = ((route / boat_speed) / 60)
    return(crash)

route = 455
boat_speed = (knot_to_km(60) + knot_to_km(70))

print(time_of_impact(route, boat_speed))
```

Remember that the general way is the latter